# Template Does Not Show Me Anything When I Use A For Loop In Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I want to show some items in my cart template, but it doesn't show me anything.

When I don't use a `for` loop, it works fine, but it shows me nothing when I use it for a loop.

My guess is, maybe something on my `Cart` class is wrong, I am not sure, but it would be great if you check it out.

**View:**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from Products.models import Product
from .forms import AddCartForm
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from decimal import Decimal

CART_SESSION_ID = 'cart'


class Cart:
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.session = request.session
        cart_session = self.session.get(CART_SESSION_ID)
        if not cart_session:
            cart_session = self.session[CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
        self.cart = cart_session

    def add_product(self, product, quantity):
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id not in self.cart:
            self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 0, 'price': str(product.price)}
        self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity
        self.save()

    def save(self):
        self.session.modified = True

    def __iter__(self):
        product_ids = self.cart.keys()
        products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
        cart = self.cart.copy()
        for product in products:
            cart[str(product.id)]['product'] = product

        for item in cart.values():
            item['total_price'] = Decimal(item['price']) * item['quantity']
            yield item


@require_POST
def add_product(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    form = AddCartForm()
    if form.is_valid():
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
        quantity = form.cleaned_data['quantity']
        cart.add_product(product=product, quantity=quantity)
    return redirect('cart:cart_details')

def cart_details(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    context = {'cart': cart}
    return render(request, 'cart/cart_details.html', context=context)
```

**Template:**

```html
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <head>
        <tr class="cart_menu">
            <td class="image">Item</td>
            <td class="description"></td>
            <td class="price">Price</td>
            <td class="quantity">Quantity</td>
            <td class="total">Total</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        <body>
            <tr>
                {% for item in cart %}
                    <td class="cart_description">
                        ********HERE I CAN NOT SEE THE PROUDUCT NAME OR PRICE AND ...*******
                        <h4><a href="#">TEST{{ item.product }}</a></h4>
                        <p>{{ item.price }}</p>
                    </td>
                {% endfor %}    
            </tr>
       </tbody>
</table>
```

**Template Pic**

[image]

**P.S : I solved the problem and posted it below here.**

Comment: When you `print(cart)` in the view, is it there?

Comment: @dacx  Thank you for your response, yeah in " def add_product " and " def cart_details " I can see "details <Cart.views.Cart object at 0x03CF97C0> " but I tried in " def __iter__", and show me nothing, also in " def __init__ " show me every time a blank dictionary even when I increase the number of the product

Comment: I saw this very same question from you couple of days ago. It's not really answerable: it requires debug, it contains only part of the solution, it is based on a _specific_ solution with not storing card anywhere except requests (am I correct in this?). `When I don't use a for loop, it works fine` please elaborate this. Without `for loop` this template contains nothing but static text, so what "works fine"?

Comment: @IvanStarostin: I solved the problem, my friend, Thank you for your attention and your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friends, after checking the codes, I realized that I was not receiving the data in the form section.
A small but important problem.
I keep this answer, maybe someone like me will face the same problem.
I just needed to add request.post into the form.

```py
def add_product(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    #########################
    form = AddCartForm(request.POST)
    #########################
    if form.is_valid():
        ...
    return redirect('cart:cart_details')
```